# Net View on linux

Tags: ubuntu

So the windows command for this is Net View.In ubuntu I tried

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

You see that is OK. But when I exec this:

```
nmap 10.2.0.0/16
```

it takes hours because of the range(4096 or something like that).Any faster way to view the IPs/PCs on a network ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scan that huge range, use
[masscan](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan). But remember, ask your admin for permission before doing that. (And if you want to "SCAN ALL THE THINGS" - search about it, it was done not that long ago)

IMHO better will be, when you just use

```
$ arp -a
```

or use samba. Samba is Linux equivalent [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory)

Use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install samba
```

and after it type

```
$ net help
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this useful post](http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?99323-net-view-in-linux) that worked for me as `net view` to list all shares of a windows box:

```
$ smbclient -L <servername> [-U <user>]
```

where user should have the domain if that's required using the following form

```
  domainname/username
```

I tried it under openSUSE and worked like a charm.
That was what I was looking for when I found your question...